# Time Trigger schedule time

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

How can I make my time trigger to sent 8am instead of 12am. My time dependent seems sending at 12am. I think salesforce default is 12am, is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce evaluates time-based workflow/ trigger on the organization’s time zone, not the user’s. Users in different time zones might see differences in behavior. I can say that your timezone might be different from the Organization's time zone.

Refer the [link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workflow_time_action_considerations.htm&type=5) to understand about the time-based trigger.